# WooCommerce - Price not including tax on mobile view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

(This question is asked over on the Wordpress Stack Overflow, but no one seems to want to answer, so I'm putting it here)

I have a quick question. I have a site `http://frenchicpaint.co.uk` Everything is fine, except...

When you view thew site on a mobile/iPad, prices are shown exclusive of tax, yet when you view the site on a desktop the prices are inclusive of tax...?

I've only just noticed it, and can't see any option to change it...

Anyone have any ideas how I can get the prices to show INCLUSIVE of tax on the mobile version?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Solved it! In woocommerce settings tax the option must be tax based on shop adress - if not the prices are shown excl tax waiting for the customers adress to calculate tax... Why it only affected the mobile view I dont know.

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day :) and this is very very strange because it's just with mobile users.

Answer (score 1):

This is a major issue that confused me for last 2 days, finnally I got a solution by exploring the woocomerece settings. All you just need to do the follwing change,

Woocomerce > general > Default customer location > **shop copuntry/region**

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered that I have the same problem :-( at http://sqoop.no/produkt/adventure-food-biff-satay/

I wonder if it appeared after one of the recent upgrades. My site is still in catalogue mode, perhaps this has an effect? Im looking for a solution and will post it here if I get it.

Comment: Welcome too Stack Overflow!  Thanks for contributing, but your response would be more appropriate as a comment than an answer (although perhaps you don't have permission yet to make comments).

Answer (score 0):

.. found this answer:

"mikejolley commented 9 days ago
You'd need to change the "Display Prices in the Shop" option based on user agent. Not something core will do for you".

Im not sure what "option based on user agent" meens, but it seems to solve the problem for the guy who posted the question.